# Input type number step validation - Custom form validation

Tags: angular, validation, input, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular application that uses a reactive form. One of my input fields is of type number and I use the *step* directive to determine valid values as following:

```
steps = 0.25
myForm: FormGroup

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  myForm = this.fb.group({
      numberControl: new FormControl(null)
  });
```

---

```
<input type="number" step="{{steps}}" formControlName="numberControl">
```

The step property can be changed based on other input of the application but for simplicity I have not included that in this example. My problem here is that the form is always valid. The step works when I use the up and down arrow keys of the input field but I could enter any value manually and it would still be valid.

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rhyeeb

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You mean to say that the number input field should only be controlled only via the stepper arrows and not through keyboard. Am I right?

Comment: No I want the form to be invalid if I manually enter a value that is not a valid step. So in my example something like 0.26

Comment: You should create then a custom validator for your input field. You can find tons of articles in google regarding that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, numner input fields don't validate if the number entered manually by user is divisible by the step counter. If you want a feature like that, then you have to implement a custom validator which is pretty easy.

All you have to do is create a function to validate the number input field and then include the newly created validator in the Validators array of the `FormControl` object. Your validator function should either return a `null` value when your custom validation test passes or return a map of key-value pairs detailing the reason for failure.

Find the below code snippet demonstrating the use of custom validator to check if the current input value is a valid step or not.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  steps = 0.25;
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      numberControl: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        this.validateNumField.bind(this)
      ])
    });

    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(_ => {
      if (!this.myForm.valid) {
        console.log('err msg -> ', this.myForm.get("numberControl").errors);
      }
    });
  }

  validateNumField(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
    let rem = control.value && Number.parseFloat(control.value) % this.steps;
    // console.log(rem);

    /**
    * If the remainder is not 0 then user has entered an invalid value
    */
    return rem ? { error: "Not a valid step" } : null;
  }
}
```

Now your submit button will not work if it is not a valid step. You can go ahead and show an error message on the template if you want using `this.myForm.get("numberControl").errors` property.

You can find an working example in stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cj6ndj). For more on custom validation, visit [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators).

**Edit:** Updated answer to capture change in steps value.

Comment: I assumed that the step property would validate the input by default. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement a custom validation yourself.

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

function stepsValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
    if (!control.value || control.value % this.steps !== 0) {
        return { error: true };
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then in your formControl declaration

```
myForm = this.fb.group({
    numberControl: new FormControl(null, this.stepsValidator.bind(this))
});
```

You must use the bind function since custom validators has a different scope than the component their in.

Answer (score 1):

To be more dynamic you can pass the `step` as a variable to the validator:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export function stepValidator(step: number): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    if (control.value) {
      return +control.value % step ? { step: { value: control.value } } : null;
    }
    return null;
  };
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```js
formGroup = this.fb.group({
  field: new FormControl(null, this.stepValidator(this.steps))
});
```

And to check for validation:

```html
<p *ngIf="formGroup.get('field')?.hasError('step')">
  Field should be a multiple of {{ this.steps }}
</p>
```